# How to order by date and make a query in multiple documents in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

i have this documents:
Meds, treatments, prontuarys and medical records. 
All those documents have an user id field,  that i use to query, my problem is that i need to query all of them and order the query by date desc to make a patient medical history,   how can i do this on mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not support JOIN.Trying to use JOIN would defeat the purpose of mongoDB.

1. You could use [DBref](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) and write your application code so that it automatically fetches these references for you.
2. you could alter your schema and use [embedded documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference).
3. You have to decide yourself to leave things exactly the way they are now and do two queries.

**Example:**

```
var myCursor = db.users.find({email:'xyz@example.com'});
var userres = myCursor.hasNext() ? myCursor.next() : null;
db.posts.find({uid : userres._id});
```

Comment: Thanks for you commend  Rajesh , but how can i implement the DBref?, i'm realy lost here , im new using mongodb, but im lovin it , could you be more spescific? , all my tables have the userID field. How can i order using DBref ?, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mongodb has entirely different ways of thinking the way you keep the data and fetch. Now let us consider your schema in RDBMS system. You will keep 6 tables including one table for User Detail. While fetching the history of the Patient you need to join all the tables which have performance penalty and index has to be joined and searched. So now in mongodb as your requirement is to display the history of the Patient when you search. You will have one collection called Patient and the rest of the information will be embedded documents example

```
                {
                  _id : OBJECTID,
                   PersonalData : {Name : "Hello", DateOfJoining : Date},
                   Meds : [{Date : ""} , {Date : {}}],
                   Treatment : [{Date : "" , Type : ""}],
                   MedicalRecords : [{} , {}]
                }
```

Now ass you data is mostly readonly , you are hardly going to update the existing data , you will only add the data and rest of the time query it. Which will be very fast as all the information is saved in the same location. Once you have got all the records you can sort in php which will be faster.